# best in place input field not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, best-in-place

I am using Best In Place gem 3.03.
My view Page code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3> Name</h3>
  <%= best_in_place @contact, :first_name %>
</div>
```

My coffee script :
users.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

The First Name is coming as Mark or any Name that is in the Database but when I click it the input field is not displaying allowing me to edit the text.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dropzone
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: put ` require best_in_place` after `require jquery`.

Comment: added that but still same issue

Comment: try this: `<%= best_in_place @contact, :first_name, :as => :input %>` also see browser console for errors if any.

Comment: There are no errors in console and there is no change same issue @G.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue looks like I was including the jquery script twice one in application.js and once using javascript include tag.